# Cmake does nothing under cygwin

Tags: opencv, cmake, cygwin

I am trying to build opencv library under cygwin and I am following [this](http://hvrl.ics.keio.ac.jp/kimura/opencv/opencv-3.0.0.html) tutorial.
Previously I have installed cygwin, gcc compiler package and cmake package, version 3.1.2. However, when I type in cmake command, nothing happens. It does not give any error messages or exit, just seems to be doing it perpetually.

Please, give me any idea of what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does `cmake --version` work? What path to `cmake` executable is? You may try to execute `cmake` using its full path.

Comment: cmake --version works perfectly.
After using full path and some googling it appeared that cygwin somehow has two versions of cmake - one in usr/bin/, which tells nothing and doesn't work, and another in /bin/, which gives the following error:
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
//share/cmake-3.1.2
CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache(). Aborting.

Comment: In fact, it is not two versions of cmake, because /usr/bin  and /bin/ are both mapped to C:\cygwin64\bin.
Then why do they give different output?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and post it in this question: [Getting cmake to work under Cygwin on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259005/getting-cmake-to-work-under-cygwin-on-windows-7).

In a word: run cmd.exe as administrator, and **mklink** a soft link from `{cygwin64}/share/` to `{cygwin64}/usr/share/`, such as:

```
mklink /J share usr\share
```