# Getting cmake to work under Cygwin on Windows 7

Tags: windows, cmake, cygwin

I installed the latest Cygwin on my Windows 7 machine: version 2.893 (64-bits). I made sure I included cmake, i.e. I was able to add several packages by running the Cygwin net release setup program again, after doing the first installation. I then tried to use cmake and made sure I invoked it from the bin directory:

```
user008@L0147816 /bin
$ ./cmake
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
//share/cmake-3.6.2
Usage

cmake [options] <path-to-source>
cmake [options] <path-to-existing-build>

Specify a source directory to (re-)generate a build system for it in the
current working directory.  Specify an existing build directory to
re-generate its build system.

Run 'cmake --help' for more information.
```

I don't know where the build directory could be. I'm relatively new to Cygwin. I hope somebody has found a solution for getting cmake installed and working properly under Cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

This looks cmake 101.

Assuming you want to just build a software download from somewhere
eg gl2ps:

```
# choosing a test area
$ cd /tmp
# downloading source
$ wget http://geuz.org/gl2ps/src/gl2ps-1.4.0.tgz
# expanding source code
$ tar -xf gl2ps-1.4.0.tgz
$ ls gl2ps-1.4.0-source/
CMakeLists.txt  COPYING.LGPL  gl2ps.h    gl2ps.tex    gl2psTestSimple.c
COPYING.GL2PS   gl2ps.c       gl2ps.pdf  gl2psTest.c  README.txt
# preparing a build area
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
# invoking cmake and pointing to the source directory 
$ cmake ../gl2ps-1.4.0-source/
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
[cut ...]
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/build

# running the build 
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target shared
[ 11%] Building C object CMakeFiles/shared.dir/gl2ps.o
...
[ 88%] Building C object CMakeFiles/gl2psTestSimple.dir/gl2psTestSimple.o
[100%] Linking C executable gl2psTestSimple.exe
[100%] Built target gl2psTestSimple
```

Instead for learning how to build with cmake, go to
https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/

Comment: Ok, I tried it with this example: https://github.com/krux02/minimal_cmake_example but I got the same errors. Also that the modules are not found in //share/cmake-3.6.2. Then one more line: "CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache(). Aborting". Cygwin != a Linux distro. Check again whether it's 101 ...

Comment: Ok, I have several cmake versions on my Windows machine and I was worried to invoke a different one - not the one installed with cygwin. That's why I did: "./cmake" from the bin directory. Now I have however realised that the right cmake executable is invoked anyway, when I open a cygwin prompt. No need to add a dot and a slash in front of the command cmake! Thus I tried to use cmake from a fresh "build" directory to build the minimum cmake example - in the way matzeri showed. Thus I got a lot further. I now stumbled upon a different issue: "Unable to find the requested Boost libraries" ...

Comment: Have you installed the boost devel package ?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the boost package and also gtest (or Google test). I placed them in 2 separate folders in /usr/local/ and I filled in the paths in file CMakeCache.txt. I was able to compile the example now with only 2 warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution I just found.

Let's name 3 directories:

- `{cygwin64-path}/bin/`: cmake.exe is here.
- `{cygwin64-path}/usr/share/`: cmake module directory (such as `cmake-3.20.0`) is here.
- `{cygwin64-path}/share/`: cmake.exe trying to find cmake-module-directory here, but it doesn't exist.

It's wired because cygwin install cmake-module-directory in `{cygwin64-path}/usr/share/`, but cmake.exe looks for the directory in `{cygwin64-path}/share/`.

So solution is simple. Each one below works.

METHOD 1: Create the directory `{cygwin64-path}/share/` and copy all relevant directories and files from `{cygwin64-path}/usr/share/` to the new directory.

METHOD 2: Create a **Symbolic links** `{cygwin64-path}/share/` to `{cygwin64-path}/usr/share/`.

- In windows 10 Administrator cmd.exe: `mklink /J share usr\share` and all works.
- Or use WSL or Cygwin64 Terminal: `ln -s usr/share share`